# How to add frame around plots and tables with a label in LRHC?

Tags: graphics

I want to take plots and tables, wrap a [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html) around them and add an `"(FOUO)"` label in the lower right hand corner. For plots, [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html) gives the frame I want, but I don't know how to get the Text to show up down in the LRHC (within the plot area is easy). For the table, [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html) gives too tight a frame to place a label in. I'm generating a large number of plots and tables that all have to be properly labeled for publication.

Thanks for all help!

mark

Answer (score 1):

[`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) is probably your friend here:

```
plot = MatrixPlot@RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, {100 , 100}];
Grid[
 {
  {plot, Null},
  {Null, "FOUO"}
  },
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1 ! I was looking at this, but initially thought it wasn't flexible enough... but I can play with padding Nulls and alignment and more or less get there. One problem with this approach is that my more complicated plots with legends and callouts get all mashed up when put in the Grid. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Rather than padding `Null` just use `Spacer` or the `ItemSize` option. Better control. If you don't want your plot to shrink give it an explicit `ImageSize` option.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1! I was too hung up trying to place text in a graphic. Appreciate the help!